# Simple rewrite rule for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in need of writing a simple mod_rewrite rule, as follows:

```
something.php ==> somehting (just get rid of the .php)
something_else.php ==> something/else (replace _ with /)
```

So, for example it would be like this:

```
www.mysite.com/something.php (would be rewritten as) www.mysite.com/something
www.mysite.com/something_else.php (would be rewritten as) www.mysite.com/something/else
```

As I am not familiar with regular expressions, I thought it would be simpler to ask someone who can do this in 5s rather than spend days (weeks? :P) learning regular expressions and mod_rewrite.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure to know what you want could you provide some sample input in the url bar and what you expect to find "behind"?
Because I suppose your "something" means "any word without _", true?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I have a very simple file structure on the server, so any page can be accessed by its own php file.

Comment: @Goro: belongs on ServerFault, as it isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Goro: Wondering if my answer worked for you or not?

Comment: @anubhava: Sort of. At least it led me to the right anwers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)\.php/?$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will do **external redirect**, in case you don't want that then remove `R=301,` flag from above.